# Table Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

Considering the following code I would like to have one different name in each cell but can not understand how to do it :

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '3em';
  tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
  tbl.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
      if (i == 2 && j == 1) {
        break;
      } else {
        var td = tr.insertCell();
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Luke'));

        td.style.border = '1px solid black';
        if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
          td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}
tableCreate();
```

Do anyone have an idea how should I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "name". It would be literally a name attribute in each cell?

Comment: You are always adding Luke! `td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Luke'));`

Comment: I think he means the content of the cell when he refers to `one different name in each cell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always adding Luke!

```
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Luke'));
```

Just create an array of names and use it inside the loop. As simple as that.

See a working snippet here:

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var names = ['Luke', 'Skywalker', 'Anakin', 'Darth', 'Vader'];

  var body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '3em';
  tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
  tbl.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
      if (i == 2 && j == 1) {
        break;
      } else {
        var td = tr.insertCell();
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(names[i]));

        td.style.border = '1px solid black';
        if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
          td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}
tableCreate();
```

Comment: Hooo thank you very much ! i'm so stupid... I nee to practice more !

Comment: an another question, i'm trying to add an another colum wich will contan an another array "Player" with the index of thoseplayer but i can't find the way to do it can you help me ? (like colum 1 = Player 1 column two = "luke" and so on)

Comment: @OlivierB Have you asked a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You can all keep different names in an array and then use it as you create your cells.

Something like below

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var namesArray = [ 'Luke', 'Hans', 'Leia', 'Chewbacca', 'Yoda'];
  
  var body = document.body,
      tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '3em';
  tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
  tbl.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
      if (i == 2 && j == 1) {
        break;
      } else {
        var td = tr.insertCell();
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(namesArray[i]));

        td.style.border = '1px solid black';
        if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
          td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}
tableCreate();
```

Comment: Yes, perfect ! tha is how it should be done, big thanks too !

Comment: @ochi The OP has only 1 point and new, might not be able to vote posts up.

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood your question , you are trying to insert different text each time. Here is how.

```js
function tableCreate(){
    var body = document.body,
        tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '3em';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
     tbl.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 1; j++){
            if(i == 2 && j == 1){
                break;
            } else {
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arguments[i]));
                
                td.style.border = '1px solid black';
                if(i == 1 && j == 1){
                    td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}
tableCreate('First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth');
```

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks it's aso a way to do it ! Big thanks !